# Vue.js disable component style with @import when changing component via router link

Tags: vue.js

I am newbie in Vue.js. I have some components with scoped style, for example:

```
<style scoped>
  @import '..resources\css\main.css';
</style>
```

And have it on another component as:

```
<style scoped>
  @import 'resources\css\admin.css';
</style>
```

And i use route for change page:

```
<template>
  <li><Link :href="route ('admin')">
  </Link></li>
  <li><Link :href="route ('main')">
  </Link></li>
</template>

<script>
  import {Link} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

  export default {
    components: {
      Link
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I go through the pages, the style of the last page is assigned to the one I switched to. How do I fix this?

For example, if I switch from component Main that uses `main.css`, to the Admin component, then the `main.css` will be assigned to the admin component.

I want that when I navigate through the pages through the route, the styles of the previous component are not assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Your scoped styles are very close; your technique works on [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869834/vue-vue-router-scoped-css-not-clearing-on-navigation). That does confirm the behavior you see: styles do not get removed after the component is loaded, so you need scoping or selectors for that.

The problem here is that under the default CSS handler, [the `@import` doesn't work with scoping](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/import-style-file-doesnt-scoped/7479). Scoped styles effectively require Vue to rewrite your CSS file *at compile time* to make sure everything is prefaced with a unique ID as a selector, and it won't reach through to an [`@import` link in native CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) to do that.

Workarounds suggested in the link include using `<style scoped src="your/path.css">`, so Vue SFC includes your content at compile time and can rewrite it; you can also install a loader for SCSS and switch to `lang="scss"` so the Sass plugin does the substitution for you at compile time.

As a last resort you can drop the `@import` rule and copy paste each file's CSS into the editor, or use specific selectors to define per-component behavior rather than SFC scoping.